# business central user personalization export

Tags: personalization, dynamics-business-central

Is there a way to export a certain user's personalizations, and use it as a user profile template?

We were thinking of having key users set up their profile the way they wanted it, then using that profile as a template for the rest of the team.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Profiles.

1. Navigate to the Profiles page
2. Edit the profile you want to configure (or create a new one)
3. Click the "Customize Pages" action in the ribbon.

This will open a new tab in the browser in configuration mode. Once you are done customizing you click "Done" in the upper right corner. The changes made to the interface will then be automatically applied to the user with the given profile.

Comment: I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-design-profiles-using-client. I was trying to export a profile.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: that solution uses the BC client. My company only uses the web interface right now.

Comment: No, it works perfectly well in the web client - at least on newer version.
Which version of Business Central are you using?